# share variable values across functions in PHP

Tags: php, function, object

I'm practising coding in an object oriented way; experimenting with taking some frequently used scripts for form handling and turning them into functions. Here is my code.

```
    class FormHandler{

        // Secure simple inputs
        public function secure($var){
                $var = stripslashes($var);
                $var = strip_tags($var);
                $var = htmlentities($var);
                return $var;
        }

        public function getAll(){
                foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                ${$key} = secure($_POST[$key]);
                }
                $didGetAll =TRUE;
        }

        public function echoResults(){
            if($didGetAll === TRUE){
                echo "Form Contents<br>";
                foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                    echo $key." => ".${$key}."<br>";
                }
            }else{
                    echo 'do getAll() fuction first'."<br>";
                }
    }
    }
```

When I run the functions like so:

```
include './formhandling.php';

$form = new FormHandler;
$form -> getAll();
$form -> echoResults();
```

it returns the 'do getAll() fuction first' message even though the $didGetAll var should = true.

I assume this is because the variable values aren't being passed between functions?

I've tried to test this by making $didGetAll global, and by doing return $didGetAll. But it still returns the same result.

Could someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant documentation to the answers below: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$didGetAll` as a property in your class to access in object.

```
class FormHandler{
    private $didGetAll = FALSE;
    // Secure simple inputs
    public function secure($var){
        $var = stripslashes($var);
        $var = strip_tags($var);
        $var = htmlentities($var);
        return $var;
    }

    public function getAll(){
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            $this->$key = $this->secure($_POST[$key]);
        }
        $this->didGetAll =TRUE;
    }

    public function echoResults(){
        if($this->didGetAll === TRUE){
            echo "Form Contents<br>";
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                echo $key." => ".$this->$key."<br>";
            }
        }else{
                echo 'do getAll() fuction first'."<br>";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for `$didGetAll` but i notice now `${$key}` echos no value presumably for the same reason. is there a similar way to do this with a dynamic variable name?

Comment: Yes, i updated my answer. If you use `$this->$key = `, create property in your object with `$key` as name. @JamieMoffat

Comment: If the answer worked, please accept it. @JamieMoffat

Comment: I'm afraid it it still only worked for the $didGetAll var. I still can't get it to work for the variable variable ${$key} I'll update my post to reflect this.

Comment: I updated my answer. If you use `$this->$key = `, create property in your object with $key as name and you can access with `$this->key` in object. @JamieMoffat

Comment: thanks, tested and this is now working, but only if i remove 'secure()' from around '$_POST[$key]' in the 'getAll()' function. apparently my 'secure()' function is causing it to break.

Answer (score 0):

Use public property for this, it`s allow to store data in variables inside class:

```
class FormHandler{
    public $didGetAll = false;

    // Secure simple inputs
    public function secure($var){
            $var = stripslashes($var);
            $var = strip_tags($var);
            $var = htmlentities($var);
            return $var;
    }

    public function getAll(){
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            ${$key} = secure($_POST[$key]);
            }
            $this->didGetAll =TRUE;
    }

    public function echoResults(){
        if($this->didGetAll === TRUE){
            echo "Form Contents<br>";
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                echo $key." => ".${$key}."<br>";
            }
        }else{
            echo 'do getAll() fuction first'."<br>";
        }
    }
} 

$form = new FormHandler;
$form -> getAll();
$form -> echoResults();
```

Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) for understand it.